# Netsuite search filter for list of items

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I am trying to add a filter in the search condition.

The problem I am facing is that while I am using the internalid and the int 1111 it works fine. But if i replace with some other column with string it does not work. It throws error in cust search line.
Can anyone suggest ?

```
        var custSearch = search.create({
        type : record.Type.CUSTOMER,
        columns : searchColumn,           
        filters: [
                 'email', 'ANYOF', ["abanks@acera.com","3m@3m.com"]]
                 //'internalid', 'ANYOF', ["1397","1251"]] // Works fine

        });
        custSearch.run().each(function(result) { // throw errors
            log.debug("Found !",result);
            return true;
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function stringFieldAnyOf(fieldId, listOfValues) {
  var result = [];
  if (listOfValues.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < listOfValues.length; i++) {
      result.push([fieldId, 'startswith', listOfValues[i]]);
      result.push('or');
    }
    result.pop(); // remove the last 'or'
  }
  return result;
}

// usage: (two more filters added just to illustrate how to combine with other filters)
var custSearch = search.create({
  type: record.Type.CUSTOMER,
  columns: searchColumn,
  filters: [
    ['companyname', 'startswith', 'A'], 'and',
    stringFieldAnyOf('email', ['abanks@acera.com', '3m@3m.com']), 'and', 
    ['companyname', 'contains', 'b']
  ]

});
```

Comment: Yes, my code is doing the same as yours, just in iterative manner. And you may use it with any string field you have (not only 'email')

Comment: If I use the filter it gives error as. I have detailed it down in my last ans.
**{"name":"WRONG_PARAMETER_TYPE","message":"Wrong parameter type: filters is expected as Array. "}**

Answer (score 5):

Email field is not compatible with ANYOF operator. Try any of the following:

- ANY
- IS
- ISEMPTY
- STARTSWITH
- CONTAINS
- ISNOT
- ISNOTEMPTY
- DOESNOTSTARTWITH
- DOESNOTCONTAIN

If you need to filter by multiple emails then you could use expressions to add "OR"s. I suggest using the Chrome extension [Netsuite: Search Export](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/netsuite-search-export/gglbgdfbkaelbjpjkiepdmfaihdokglp) to make things easier.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the Search Export plugin.  That's very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**options.filters** that you are using could be:

- a single search.Filter object
- an array of search.Filter objects
- a search filter expression
- an array of search filter expressions

In your example, you create 2 Filter Objects (filterscust1 and filterscust2). After that you **try** to create a search filter expression, combining two Filter Objects with 'or' string inside. But this is not correct:

A search filter expression is a JavaScript **string array** of zero or more elements. Each element is one of the following:

- Operator - either ‘NOT', ‘AND', or ‘OR'
- Filter term
- Nested search filter expression

So, the equivalent code should be:

```js
filterscust1 = ['email', 'contains', '3m@3m.com'];

filterscust2 = ['email', 'contains', 'abanks@acera.com'];

var filtersExp = [ filterscust1, 'or', filterscust2 ];

var custSearch = search.create({
  type: record.Type.CUSTOMER,
  columns: searchColumn,
  filters: [filtersExp]

});
```

or directly:

```js
var custSearch = search.create({
  type: record.Type.CUSTOMER,
  columns: searchColumn,
  filters: [ ['email', 'contains', '3m@3m.com'], 'or', 
             ['email', 'contains', 'abanks@acera.com']
           ]

});
```

Comment: Thanks... This code works for me. The above array exception is no more.